# Android saying resource file not found

Tags: java, android

I have only done xml and have not moved onto the java yet, however I cannot run the program on my emulator as it keeps throwing me the same error. I have looked at other questions like mine and cannot find an answer that works.

I have tried cleaning and re-building my project

This is the xml code I have

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.widget.RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/gradient"
    tools:context="MainActivity">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/logoView"
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/download"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/usernameText"
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:background="#11000000"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Username"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:textSize="16dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="35dp"
        android:layout_above="@+id/passwordText"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/passwordText"
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:background="#11000000"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="@string/password"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        android:layout_marginBottom="130dp"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/btnLogin"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/usernameText"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/usernameText"
        android:autofillHints="" />

    <android.widget.Button
        android:text="@string/login"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:id="@+id/btnLogin"
        android:layout_marginBottom="31dp"
        android:layout_above="@+id/linkRegister"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">
    </android.widget.Button>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/lblLogin"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:text="@string/login"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            android:textSize="18sp" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/linkRegister"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/register_here"
        android:layout_above="@+id/linearLayout"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="6dp" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout">
    </LinearLayout>
</android.widget.RelativeLayout>
```

This is the java code I have at the moment

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
}
```

This is the error that I am having

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.androidtask2/com.example.androidtask2.MainActivity}: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f09001c
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2416)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
     Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f09001c
        at android.content.res.Resources.getValue(Resources.java:1351)
        at android.content.res.Resources.loadXmlResourceParser(Resources.java:2774)
        at android.content.res.Resources.getLayout(Resources.java:1165)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:421)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:469)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140)
        at com.example.androidtask2.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:10)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Answer (score 0):

It's quite a common error. Try cleaning your project and rebuilding it:

From the Menu bar-

**Build > Clean Project**

After this,

**Build > Rebuild Project**

Comment: Thanks yeah I tried that before but I managed to fix the problem. Think something went wrong during when android built my project. I just copied my xml code and made a new project and that worked.

Comment: @C.Lubbe I see, that's cool. I'm not really sure, but this kinda error MAY (maybe someone else can confirm) usually occur when some java files or directories are moved and Android Studio gets confused. Although I'm not sure about this, but usually Invalidate Cache and Restart helps in this situation too.